# Can webpack-dev-server serve multiple HTML files?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to build multiple HTML files, each with a separate entry point. Seems like webpack-dev-server is only serving a single HTML file.

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798095/multiple-html-files-using-webpack). Did you solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can take advantage of npm script and have to separate configs.

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "build-first-app": "webpack-dev-server --env=first",
  "build-second-app": "webpack-dev-server --env=second"
}
```

webback.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(env) {
  return require(`./webpack.config.${env}.js`)
};
```

Now you need to separate files(webpack.config.first.js and webpack.config.second.js) each with there own webpack configuration.
Run the command npm run build-first-app to display the first app and npm run build-second-app for the second.

Comment: That's not answering his question.