# Multiple html files using webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to do something in a project that I'm not sure if it is possible, I am in a wrong way or misunderstanding something. We are using webpack, and the idea is to serve more than one html file.

localhost:8181 -> serves index.html
localhost:8181/example.html -> serves example.html

I'm trying to do it by setting multiple entry points, following the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html):

The folder structure is:

```
/
|- package.json
|- webpack.config.js
  /src
   |- index.html
   |- example.html
   | /js
      |- main.js
      |- example.js
```

Webpack.config.js:

```
...
entry: {
    main: './js/main.js',
    exampleEntry: './js/example.js'
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'target'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].bundle_[chunkhash].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[file].map'
},
...
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
<head>
    ...
    <link type="text/css" href="/style/default.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="/main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

example.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
<head>
    ...
    <link type="text/css" href="/style/default.css">
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="/example.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Somebody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to find the solution for this ? 
I am also looking for the same use case.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

See an entrypoint as the root of a tree that references many other assets like javascript modules, images, templates and so on. When you define more than one entrypoint, you basically split your assets into so called chunks to not have all your code and assets in one single bundle.

What I think you want to achieve is to have more than one "index.html" for different apps that also refer to different chunks of your assets which you already defined with your entrypoints.

Copying an index.html file or even generating one with references to these entrypoints is not handled by the entrypoint mechanism - it is the other way round. A basic approach for handling html pages is using the `html-webpack-plugin` which not only can copy html files but also has an extensive mechanism for templating. This is especially helpful if you want to have your bundles suffixed with a bundle hash that is pretty to avoid browser caching issues when you update your app.

As you have defined a name pattern as `[id].bundle_[chunkhash].js` you can no longer reference your javascript bundle as `main.bundle.js` as it will be called something like `main.bundle_73efb6da.js`.

Have a look at the [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin). Especially relevant for your use case:

- [Generating multiple html files](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin#generating-multiple-html-files)
- [Filtering chunks](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin#filtering-chunks)

You should probably have something like that in the end (warning: not tested)

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: 'src/index.html',
    chunks: ['main']
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'example.html',
    template: 'src/example.html',
    chunks: ['exampleEntry']
  })
]
```

Please be aware to reference the name of the entrypoint in the chunks array, so in your example this should be `exampleEntry`. Probably it's also a good idea to move your templates into a specific folder instead of having them in directly inside the root src folder.

Comment: Good  explanation but it still bothers me that you have to call 'new HTMLWebPlugin ' for every different page you create in your project.

Comment: Everyone does not like to call the 'new HTMLWebPlugin' each of the pages. Need alternative.

Comment: @Tahzzot then write a loop, the config file is just Javascript!

Comment: where/how do you specifiy `[id].bundle_[chunkhash].js`

Answer (score 48):

### To use *Multiple HTML* files in `Webpack` using *HtmlWebpackPlugin* :

> Modify the `webpack.config.js` by directly embedding the below code.

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

let htmlPageNames = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4'];
let multipleHtmlPlugins = htmlPageNames.map(name => {
  return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: `./src/${name}.html`, // relative path to the HTML files
    filename: `${name}.html`, // output HTML files
    chunks: [`${name}`] // respective JS files
  })
});

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './js/main.js',
    example1: './js/example1.js',
    //... repeat until example 4
  },
  module: { 
       //.. your rules
  };
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      chunks: ['main']
    })
  ].concat(multipleHtmlPlugins)
  
};
```

You can add as many HTML pages as required to the `htmlPageNames` array. Ensure that each HTML and corresponding JS file have the same name (The above code assumes that).

Comment: I had to do `excludeChunks: ["main"]` to prevent bundle meant for my index.html from appearing in my other html too.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me with the changes that @kyw suggested and also, by using placeholder in output, like so:
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: ''
  },

Comment: This is a great approach.  But it's not working for me.  I keep getting the message: `Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html` Any ideas what's happening to my file?

Comment: I'm answering my own question now.  I discovered that using the `filename` is a "must have"!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [Copy Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) if you don't need two different builds, i.e., assuming that you just want to serve a different HTML with the same `main.bundle.js`.

The plugin is really dead simple (only tested in webpack v4):

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './src/example.html', to: './example.html' }
    ])
  ]
}
```

Then in `example.html` you can load the build from `index.html`. E.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
<head>
    ...
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"> Show an example </div>
    <script src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any other way possible to use CopyWebpackPlugin and add bundle.js file to html file through webpack instead of directly giving script reference in the html file itself ?

Comment: @SritamJagadev No, CopyWebpackPlugin just copies files literally. You need WebpackHtmlPlugin if you want to modify the HTML, like injecting script tags.

Answer (score 3):

RICHARD ABRAHAM's solution worked well for me i also added fsreaddir function for detect html files

```
let htmlPageNames = [];
const pages = fs.readdirSync('./src')
pages.forEach(page => {
    if (page.endsWith('.html')) {
        htmlPageNames.push(page.split('.html')[0])
    }
})
console.log(htmlPageNames);
```

Answer (score 2):

Going back to @andreas-jägle point. Use 'html-webpack-plugin':html-webpack-plugin [html-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/). However optimise your code to avoid **duplication** of files:

```js
  plugins: ['index', 'page1', 'page2'].map(
    (file) =>
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/' + file + '.html',
        inject: true,
        chunks: ['index', 'main'],
        filename: './' + file + '.html' //relative to root of the application
      })
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution, assuming Webpack ^4.44.1.  That is, importing the HTML in your JS/TS app.

Sample webpack.config.js

```js
    const path = require('path');
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
    
    
    module.exports = {
        entry: { app: './src/index.ts' },
    
        mode: 'development',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                title: 'Development',
                template: path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'index.ejs')
            }),
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    use: 'ts-loader',
                    include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/i,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: '[name].[ext]'
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    // this exclude is required
                    exclude: path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'index.html')
                }
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
            compress: true,
            port: 3900
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        },
    };
```

Corresponding app

```
import './about.html';
    
console.log('this is a test');
```

index.ejs

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Question</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <a href="./about.html">About</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

about.html

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>About</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is an about page</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Webpack will copy about.html to the corresponding *output* folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
plugins: [
  ...templates.map(template => new HtmlWebpackPlugin(template))
]
```

This code would help if you have a lot of templates :)

Comment: Can you write out the whole code? It's not really clear.

Comment: @RockyKev
I don't remember the context, but the main point is to have a variable to store information about your templates. Then you can run your templates trough webpack and compile them if you need to. 

` const templates = [ { template: './src/hbs/pages/index.hbs', filename: './index.html' }, { template: './src/hbs/pages/index.hbs', filename: './articles/index.html' } ]` (sorry for bad formatting)

Answer (score 1):

in 2024 can be used the  [html-bundler-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin) instead of `html-webpack-plugin`. This plugin extracts JS, CSS, assets from source files used in HTML. Using this plugin, the `entrypoint` is the HTML file and all used source resources are extracted automatically.

You can load individual source scripts, styles and images directly in HTML.
The path to source file must be relative by HTML file or an Webpack alias.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
<head>
    ...
    <!-- load source file of style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/default.scss">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <!-- load source file of image -->
    <img src="./images/homepage.png">
    <!-- load source file of script -->
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

example.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
<head>
    ...
    <!-- load source file of style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/default.scss">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <!-- load source file of script -->
    <script src="./js/example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Install plugin:

```
npm install html-bundler-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Change your webpack.config.js according to the following minimal configuration:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  entry: {
    // define HTML files here
    index: './src/index.html',  // => dist/index.html
    example: './src/example.html', // => dist/example.html
    // ...
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      js: {
        // JS output filename extracted from source script loaded in HTML via `<script>` tag
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
      },
      css: {
        // CSS output filename extracted from source style loaded in HTML via `<link>` tag
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
      },
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      // styles
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      // images
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|ico)/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'img/[name].[hash:8][ext]',
        },
    },
    ],
  },
};
```

The generated HTML contains output hashed filenames. Source styles, scripts and images are automatically processed and placed in the output directory `dist/`.

The generated index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <link href="/assets/css/default.f57966f4.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <img src="/assets/img/homepage.d2f4b855.png">
    <script src="/assets/js/main.b855d8f4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> **Note**
>
> No longer needed to import styles in JavaScript.
> No longer needed to define a JS file as the entrypoint.
> Now it works intuitively, right in the HTML.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!