# Webpack 2 html files with separate builds

Tags: css, iframe, webpack, bundle, webpack-4

I want to setup a project that has 2 html files: `index.html` and `iframe.html`.

The `index.html` should have injected the bundle that comes from `index.js` file, but for `iframe.html` I would like to inject the bundle that comes from dependencies that are included in `iframe.js` file.

I've got a webpack (common) configuration for 2 entry points:

```
entry: {
 app: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/scripts/index.js'),
 iframe: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/scripts/iframe.js')
},
output: {
  path: Path.join(__dirname, '../build'),
  filename: 'js/[name].js'
},
```

But it seems that both `html` files got injected full bundles - how can I split it? (and make sure that `index.js` will not contain/share the code from `iframe.js` file?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798095/multiple-html-files-using-webpack) I've found a solution:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: 'index.html',
  template: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.html'),
  chunks: ['app']
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: 'iframe.html',
  template: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/iframe.html'),
  chunks: ['iframe']
})
```