# Add custom vanilla javascript functions to webpack-encore workflow configuration

Tags: javascript, function, twig, config, webpack-encore

You'll find alot of ressources about setting up "vanilla" webpack configurations to suit your needs on the internet. However, I'm having a hard time adapting those "vanilla" webpack solutions for use with webpack-encore!

Here's an example with [configuring webpack to generate HTML assets out of TWIG/JSON source files](https://dgrigg.com/blog/twig-webpack).

So far, I managed to make it work by using [webpack-encore's .addLoader() and .addPlugin() built-in methods](http://devfrontend.info/webpack-encore-generer-des-fichiers-html-a-partir-de-templates-twig/). But there's a huge caveat: my adaptation is pretty much static as I have to manually declare a new plugin for each TWIG page I want to be rendered as HTML:

```js
Encore
[...]
    .addLoader({
        test: /\.twig$/,
        type: 'asset/source',
        loader: 'twig-html-loader'
    })
    .addPlugin(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Index',
        filename: '../html/index.html',
        template: './assets/twig/index.twig',
        publicPath: '../build/'
    }))
    .addPlugin(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Bio',
        filename: '../html/pages/bio.html',
        template: './assets/twig/bio.twig',
        publicPath: '../../build/'
    }))
;
```

"vanilla" webpack configuration's sample is much better as the author [wrote and made use of two custom functions](https://gist.github.com/dgrigg/d4811ee9bc85d31376f4cb7365abf04d#file-webpack-config-js-L24) that recursively read through the main twig directory and make a list of the templates in all the folders, keeping the paths intact and excluding all the template files.

He then [passes his custom "htmlPlugins" immediately invoqued function to the whole module.exports = { module.plugins } webpack configuration tree as an argument of the .concat() method](https://gist.github.com/dgrigg/d4811ee9bc85d31376f4cb7365abf04d#file-webpack-config-js-L167).

This is my very first experience with webpack/webpack-encore and I have absolutely no clue about how to use those vanilla javascript "walk" and "htmlPlugins" function with webpack-encore.

Any help, even keywords to guide me to new Google searches paths, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I needed to do this kind of code, but with webpack-encore instead of classic webpack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63385300/1662176

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured it out myself.

```js
// create a list of twig files to generate
// filter out anything that starts with an underscore or is not a twig file
function walk(dir) {
    let results = [];
    const list = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    list.forEach(file => {
        file = `${dir}/${file}`;
        const stat = fs.statSync(file);
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory() && path.basename(file).indexOf('_') !== 0) {
            /* Recurse into a subdirectory */
            results = results.concat(walk(file));
        } else if (
            stat &&
            !stat.isDirectory() &&
            path.extname(file) === '.twig' &&
            path.basename(file).indexOf('_') !== 0
        ) {
            /* Is a file */
            results.push(file);
        }
    });
    return results;
}

//start looking in the main twig folder
const files = walk('./assets/twig');

// generate html plugins to export
const htmlPlugins = files.map(
    file =>
        // Create new HTMLWebpackPlugin with options
        Encore.addPlugin(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: '../html/' + file.replace('./assets/twig/', '').replace('.twig', '.html'),
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, file),
            publicPath: '../build/',
            hash: true,
        }))
);
```