# Webpack config for multiple pages with firebase 9

Tags: javascript, webpack

I build a webpack to my project which using firebase 9 to collect page data from documents which is working like a charm in my index.html page. My problem is when i try to add another html page for admin panel it doesn't work my problem is if i am right i need to change my webpack.config.js but don't know how. my webpack.config.js is

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js', 
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  watch: true
}
```

my goal is add another page which is adminpanel.html and use it same as index.html everything controls from index.js in index.html and with watch: true i can see everything in real time please help me
my package.json is

```
{
  "name": "firebase-9",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.67.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.6.4"
  }
}
```

my project structure is

```
--dist
    -adminpanel.html
    -index.html
    -bundle.js
--node_modules
--src
    -index.js
package-lock.json
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

Comment: I edited it with structure

Comment: did u ask yourself why you use webpack?

Comment: yes i need it for later steps normaly i  make it with vue but with vue having problems with styling and can't use every javascript so i want to build it in html5 with pure javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple html files using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798095/multiple-html-files-using-webpack)

Comment: nope i tried them but still get an error on adminpanel.html